# How to write automated tests - Test case as a function or test case as a class

Tags: java, python, testing, frameworks, automation

I am having a design problem in test automation:-

Requirements - Need to test different servers (using unix console and not GUI) through automation framework. Tests which I'm going to run - Unit, System, Integration

Question: While designing a test case, I am thinking that a Test Case should be a part of a test suite (test suite is a class), just as we have in Python's pyunit framework. But, should we keep test cases as functions for a scalable automation framework or should be keep test cases as separate classes(each having their own setup, run and teardown methods) ? From automation perspective, Is the idea of having a test case as a class more scalable, maintainable or as a function?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Test Cases are used as classes rather than functions because each test case has own setup data and initialization mechanism. Implementing test cases as a single function will not only make difficult to set up test data before running any test case, but yes you can have different test method in a test case class if you are running same test scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my opinion:

**Pros of writing tests as functions:**

- If you need any pre-requisites for that test case, just call another function which provides the pre-requisites. Do the same thing for teardown steps
- Looks simple for a new person in the team. Easy to undertstand what is happening by looking into tests as functions

**Cons of writing tests as functions:**

- Not maintainable - Because if there are huge number of tests where
  same kind of pre-requisites are required, the test case author has to
  maintain calling each pre-requisite function in the test case. Same
  for each teardown inside the test case
- If there are so many calls to such a pre-requisite function inside many test cases, and if anything changes in the product functionality etc, you have to manually make efforts in many places again.

**Pros of writing test cases as classes:**

- Setup, run and teardown are clearly defined. the test pre-requisites are easily understood
- If there is Test 1 which is does something and the result of Test 1 is used as a setup pre-requisite in Test 2 and 3, its easy to just inherit from Test 1, and call its setup, run a teardown methods first, and then, continue your tests. This helps make the tests independent of each other. Here, you dont need to make efforts to maintain the actual calling of your code. It will be done implicitly because of inheritance.
- Sometimes, if the setup method of Test 1 and run method of Test 2 might become the pre-requisites of another Test 3. In that case, just inherit from both of Test 1 and Test 2 classes and in the Test 3's setup method, call the setup of Test 1 and run of Test 2. Again you dont need to need to maintain the calling of the actual code, because you are calling the setup and run methods, which are tried and tested from the framework perspective.

**Cons of writing test case as classes:**

- When the number of tests increase, you cant look into a particular test and say what it does, because it may have inherited so much levels that you cant back track. **But, there is a solution around it - Write doc strings in each setup, run, teardown method of each test case**. And, write a custom wrapper to generate doc strings for each test case. While/After inheriting, you should provide an option to add/Remove the docstring of a particular function (setup, run, teardown) to the inherited function. This way, you can just run that wrapper and get information about a test case from its doc-strings